# Statistics - Exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

There are $n$ machines. Each has durability given by exponential distribution with $EX = 10$. If a dead machine is replaced with new one immediately, find minimal $n$ so we can say with $P = 0.99$ that total durability will be at least $1100$?

I know that i need to get Binomial distribution and approximate it by Normal distribution but i do not know how do get there. The way this task is written is also confusing me a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having $n$ different machines all break down can be interpreted as the same machine breaking down $n$ times, since the the time to breaking is exponentially distributed and thus memoryless.

Let $X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ be the random variable that models how many times the machine breaks down in one time step. We have $\lambda = \operatorname{E}(X) = \frac{1}{10}$, since the break down rate is $\frac{1}{10}$. Now we have $Y \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(1100\lambda)$, which models the number of machines that break down in $1100$ time steps.

We want to find $y$ such that $\Pr(Y \leq y) = 0.99$, where $y$ denotes the number of machines required. Now we can model a $\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ distribution with high $\lambda$ as a normal distribution with mean and variance equal to $\lambda$, so we approximate $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(110,110)$.

Since we know $Z = \frac{Y-\mu}{\sigma}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $\Pr(Z\leq 2.326)=0.99$, we need to solve for $$\frac{y-\mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2}}=2.326 \implies y = 2.326 \sqrt{110}+110 = 134.4,$$ hence we need $135$ machines to assure a $99\%$ probability that the total durability will be at least $1100$ time steps.

Comment: I am grateful for your in depth explanation. One side question, you used $λ$ from exponential distribution which is $1/10$ ?

Comment: Yes, since the expected time for one machine to break down is $10$, the rate parameter $\lambda = \frac{1}{10}$.

Comment: Can you explain why you set $Pr(Y < y)$ instead of $Pr(Y > y)$. The task says, to find minimal number(that means that numbers above are also acceptable), or am i wrong ?

Comment: $Y$ is the number of machines that break down in $1100$ time steps, while $y$ is the number of machines that we have. Therefore, if $Y>y$, all machines break down. We want to find the number $y$ such that $\Pr(Y < y) = 0.99$, or in words, we want to find the minimum number of machines needed in our inventory such that in $99\%$ of the times, not all our machines will break down.